# Flutter - Cannot add event while adding a stream

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, dart-pub

I'm using [battery_info][1] in my ongoing project.

I want to use StreamProvider to collect data of battery and use it throughout my app, wherever necessary.

Let me add this, I'm working with stream for the first time. So did a lot of research about streams and how they work and especially, StreamProvider().

From my research and understanding so far, I came to know that StreamProvider emits data only to its descendents.

So I wrote this so far,

1. main.dart

```
return Provider(
      create: (_) => BatteryInformation(),
      child: HomeScreen()
```

2. home_screen.dart

```
Expanded(
    child: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.amber,
     ),
    child: StreamProvider<AndroidBatteryInfo?>.value(
    initialData: AndroidBatteryInfo(),
    value: batteryInfo.androidBatteryStream,
    child: BatteryDetails(),
    )
   ),
 ),
```

3. Provider class

```
class BatteryInformation {
  final int? voltage;
  final String? chargingStatus;
  final int? batteryLevel;
  final double? batteryCapacity;
  final String? technology;
  final bool? batteryPresence;
  final int? scale;
  final double? remainingEnergy;
  final int? temperature;
  final String? pluggedStatus;
  final double? currentAverage;
  final String? batteryConnectedStatus;

  BatteryInformation({
    this.voltage,
    this.chargingStatus,
    this.batteryLevel,
    this.batteryCapacity,
    this.technology,
    this.batteryPresence,
    this.scale,
    this.remainingEnergy,
    this.temperature,
    this.pluggedStatus,
    this.currentAverage,
    this.batteryConnectedStatus,
  });

  StreamController<AndroidBatteryInfo?>? _androidBatteryStreamController =
      StreamController<AndroidBatteryInfo?>();

  Stream<AndroidBatteryInfo?>? get androidBatteryStream =>
      _androidBatteryStreamController?.stream;

  void fetchLatestBatteryInfo() {
    _androidBatteryStreamController?.sink
        .addStream(BatteryInfoPlugin().androidBatteryInfoStream);
  }

  void dispose() {
    _androidBatteryStreamController?.close();
  }
```

In the same file, there are two funtions

```
factory BatteryInformation.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    return BatteryInformation(
      voltage: data['voltage'] ?? '',
      chargingStatus: data['chargingStatus'] ?? '',
      batteryLevel: data['batteryLevel'] ?? '',
      batteryCapacity: data['batteryCapacity'] ?? '',
      technology: data['technology'] ?? '',
      batteryPresence: data['present'] ?? '',
      scale: data['scale'] ?? '',
      remainingEnergy: data['remainingEnergy'] ?? '',
      temperature: data['temperature'] ?? '',
      pluggedStatus: data['pluggedStatus'] ?? '',
      currentAverage: data['currentAverage'] ?? '',
      batteryConnectedStatus: data['chargingStatus'] ?? '',
    );
  }

  factory BatteryInformation.initialData() {
    return BatteryInformation(
      voltage: 0,
      chargingStatus: '',
      batteryLevel: 0,
      batteryCapacity: 0.0,
      technology: '',
      batteryPresence: false,
      scale: 0,
      temperature: 0,
      pluggedStatus: '',
      currentAverage: 0.0,
      batteryConnectedStatus: '',
    );
  }
```

Yet I'm getting the error "Bad State  = Cannot add event while adding a stream"
[1]: https://pub.dev/packages/battery_info

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late to answer.

You can use it directly as:

```
StreamBuilder(
            stream: BatteryInfoPlugin().androidBatteryInfoStream,
            builder: (context, snapshot){
              ...
```

Hope it help. :-)